# Cross Compiled V4L2 of embedded Linux

Tags: cross-compilation, embedded-system, v4l

Hello all I am new to Embedded Linux. I am having embedded hardware running Linux 5. I want to enable a webcam on it but i dont have internet access or a compiler installed. So i cross compiled V4L2 with the right compiler and copied the files to the usr/lib folder.
I cant use terminal commads such as 'v4l2-utils' though. Is there anything else i need to do to you use such commands or is this just not possible om embedded devices and i can only use the libraries in cross compiled C files for example ?

Thank you very much for any insight

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *SE Unix & Linux provides support for Linux, BSD or Unix system, this is a Ubuntu Q&A site*